# coloring product images in flash/flex approach?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I will redesign a product page that contains products like Vase, Ceramic Plates and more,  Customers can customize the colors of the product. Now I need some advice what approach would best fit, I am planning to use Flash/Flex/Actionscript in implementing this; That way I can minimize loading to many jpegs for the product and at the same time making the page more interactive. I'm looking if there are some examples out there to get me starting.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem for my current employer, that sells dresses. You can't colorize an item, without providing a really good mask (and the color is solid), I also suppose that drawing masks for every product I'ts far more complex and expensive that having 3 - 4 photos for each.

Comment: Yeah you have a point. Some of the product will really have custom colors and will not be limited 3-4 colors; Example there are colored strips in the vase and users can customize the colors of the strip and also the color of the vase. Regarding creating  the mask, I think that would not be a really big problem since shapes are not really too complex. Hope you have an Idea for this! Thanks!